# How to pass StringGrid Row Number to another form?

Tags: delphi, stringgrid

I have a StrinGrid component and a procedure:

```
procedure TForm3.StringGrid1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SelectedElement := stringgrid1.Cells[0,stringgrid1.Row];
end
```

SelectedElement is declared in public section:

```
public
SelectedElement : String;
end;
```

When I use it in this unit, for example `Label1.Caption := SelectedElement`, it works fine. But in another unit, where I specified `uses unit1` in `implementation`, and I try to use this variable like this `Label1.Caption := Form1.SelectedElement` it sets label to empty string. But when I set variable manually for example on first form create, then this value shows up in second form, even if variable is later changed to value from stringgrid.

Comment: I have a vague feeling that you want the label on the second form to reflect the selected element whenever you click on a cell of the grid of the first form. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to wait for change, only show the element that was selected while opening second form via button on first form

Comment: I can't guess why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Given the small amount of code you have shown so far, it is difficult to diagnose your problem for sure, but based on your comments so far, it sounds to me like you are probably dynamically creating your `TForm3` object at run-time using `TForm3.Create()` and not assigning the object to the global `Form3` pointer, but are trying to use the global `Form3` pointer to access the `SelectedElement` value.  Is that correct?

Also, you show `TForm3.StringGrid1Click()` is setting `TForm3.SelectedElement`, but you are accessing `Form1.SelectedElement` instead of `Form3.SelectedElement`.  Does `TForm1` have its own `SelectedElement` member?  Or are you not showing your real code copy/pasted from your real project?

Comment: +1 this is the only explanation that I can believe matches the stated behaviour

Comment: The code is real, Form1 does not have it's own SelectedElement. Form3 is my main form, and it creates Form1 by `Form1 := TForm1.Create(Application);`. `Form1.SelectedElement` was a mistake, I changed it to `Form3.SelectedElement`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a property to the form that returns the desired value:

```
....
private
  function GetSelectedElement: string;
public
  property SelectedElement: string read GetSelectedElement;
....
```

And implement it like this:

```
function TForm3.GetSelectedElement: string;
begin
  Result := StringGrid1.Cells[0, StringGrid1.Row];
end;
```

This will always return the current state which I believe is what you want.

Comment: Now this always sets the SelectedElement value to column 0 row 0, and not the selected row when I read the value in the second form; when I read it in first form it works.

Comment: @user1766392: The only way it can do that is if `StringGrid1.Row` really is 0.  Reading `Form3.SelectedElement` in `Form2` will work fine, provided that `Form3` is pointing at a valid `TForm3` object to begin with.

Comment: @user Ask yourself how that could be so. As Remy says, you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I got it to work, but only if I put code to set label in form2 in unit1. Does the job. Thanks for help!

Comment: It will work either way if you do it right. I think you need to learn some basics. Clearly you have multiple instances of the form. Remy probably diagnosed it right.

Comment: @user - form2? Please consider posting real code when asking a question.